# Error al recibir arreglo

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, array

Tengo este codigo javascript que envia un arreglo de checkbox

```
    $('#enviar').click(function() {

                    let valoresCheck = [];

                    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(){
                        valoresCheck.push(this.value);
                    });

                    console.log(valoresCheck);
                    //alert(valoresCheck);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "acciones/doc_cambio_usr.php",
                        type: 'post',
                        dataType: 'html',
                        data: valoresCheck,
                    })
                    .done(function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
});


                });
```

el cual al llegar a la url acciones/doc_cambio_usr.php lo separo de la sigueinte manera

```
  foreach($_POST as $posicion=>$usuario)
 {
    echo "El " . $posicion . " es " . $usuario;
    echo "<br>";
 }
```

y en la consola me imprime   este error y no el array

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En PHP haz un `var_dump($_POST);`, edita tu pregunta y agrega el resultado para saber lo que realmente estás recibiendo y cómo puedes manejarlo.

Comment: @GGvv en vez de `type=checkbox` usa el nombre del checkbox ejemplo: `input[name="checkBoxes[]"]:checked` ten en cuenta que **checkBoxes[]** es el name de los input del tipo checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que está enviando los datos sin su respectivo `name`.
Intente usar algo como esto:

```
            let valoresCheck = {};

            $(form + ' input').each(function() {
                if(this.value != '') {
                    valoresCheck[this.name] = this.value; 
                }
            });
```